# Update table with random values from another table without duplicates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to update a column in a MySQL table that contains string values with values from another table that contains unique names, but without repeating the same values.

Each name in the 'names' table has a unique id from 1 - 1001.
There are 161 names in the target table.

I tried something like this, but it fetches duplicate entries:

```
UPDATE table_to_update
SET name = 
    ( SELECT name FROM `names` 
      WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(id) FROM `names`)) ) 
     LIMIT 1 ) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option if you are using MySQL 8+, which supports `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
UPDATE table_to_update t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM table_to_update
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM (SELECT name, id FROM names ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 161) t
) t3
    ON t2.rn = t3.rn
SET
    t1.name = t3.name;
```

Note that I hard-coded the `LIMIT` value to be 161 in the subquery, given that you know the size of the target table.  This value could be made dynamic as well, but would require more work.